# Azure SQL - table a lot larger than stored data

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I migrated my DB from onpremise SQL to Azure SQL. I store XML (aproximately 50 000 characters) in Data column (see table definition bellow). I recreated the table but still every row takes up almost 1MB of space.

Can I somehow decrease table space? Can I improve table design?

```
EXEC sp_spaceused N'dbo.OcrDocument';  

name        rows    reserved    data       index_size   unused
OcrDocument 305     231184 KB   231112 KB  16 KB        56 KB


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OcrDocument](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Filename] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [MD5Checksum] [char](32) NULL,
    [Data] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [TaskId] [char](36) NULL,
    [ResponseUrl] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [DocumentStatus] [varchar](16) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OcrDocument] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: If you want my advice we used to do exactly the same thing and we soon realised with all that text we'd fill the DB, after only a while we were using 126GB of the 250GB allowance. This also means any restore in the event of an issue takes a long time, so we migrated the text data out of the DB and store it in Blob storage and now the DB is 1.2GB and we can restore it in a few minutes if necessary. While not an answer I would strongly recommend moving the XML to blob storage.

Comment: If you want to decrease table space, I suggest you store your xml file in other cloud storage. You just store the link and your file name in the SQL table.

Comment: I tried restoring old OnPremise SQL backup of this databse and I see the sizes are simmilar. So this is expected behavior. Blob storage is good advice. Thanks.

Comment: @MiroslavAdamec If you have solved your issue, could you please post your answer?  It may help more people.

Answer (score 0):

To help more people who are at risk of experiencing this problem, I summarize the solution here

> ***Issue: When we need to store big data(such as file, image) in Azure SQL, how to do***

When store big data(such as file, image) in Azure SQL, we can firstly store these data in one cloud storage(such as Azure Storage, Sharepoint, OneDrive ). Then we can just store the url and some other information you need in Azure SQL. It will reduce Azure SQL's storage.